# JSP FileUpload [fie chosen from windows machine to be uploaded to unix machine]

Tags: jsp, file-upload

Can we upload a file chosen from windows machine to Unix server using JSP FileUpload? I am using FileItem's write method to write the file to the disk, it doesn't throw any exception but file is not created/written.

Comment: Check for access in folder. However I am sure it is doable. Most of J2ee servers are in unix.

Comment: Hey, thanks but the folder is accessible and I have added the write filepermission in catalina.policy. I am not sure but can it be due to different operating systems?

Comment: String filePath = context.getInitParameter("file-upload");DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);                                 Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();
while ( i.hasNext () ) {
 FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next(); 
 String fileName = fi.getName();           
 file = new File( filePath + fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;                                                                                               fi.write( file ) ; }

Comment: Any solution guys? Or any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked fine for me. Copying file from windows to Unix  does not create any issues. Thanks.

```
    <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.DiskFileUpload"%> 
    <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem"%> 
    <%@ page import="java.util.List"%> 
    <%@ page import="java.util.Iterator"%> 
    <%@ page import="java.io.File"%> 

    <% 
            ServletContext context = pageContext.getServletContext();
            final String SERVER_PATH = context.getInitParameter("file-upload");

            try { 
                DiskFileUpload fu = new DiskFileUpload(); 
                // If file size exceeds, a FileUploadException will be thrown        
                fu.setSizeMax(100000000); 
                List fileItems = fu.parseRequest(request);  
                Iterator itr = fileItems.iterator(); 
                while(itr.hasNext()) { 
                    FileItem fi = (FileItem)itr.next(); 

                    //Check if not form field so as to only handle the file inputs                
                    if(!fi.isFormField()) { 
                    String extension = fi.getName(); 
                    extension = extension.substring(extension.lastIndexOf("\\")+1);  
                    File fNew= new File(SERVER_PATH, extension); 
                    fi.write(fNew); 
                    } 
                  } 
            } catch(Exception e) { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 

            }   

    %>
```